# Birthday formatting with edit text

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am creating an app where I need to ask the users for the birthdate, Month/Day/Year
I would love to do it simialiar to how tinder does theirs.

if a users attempts to type (lets say) 2 in the month field it will not accept the input only allowing the user to type vaild dates so for Feb you need to type 02. like wises if the user types 1 then tried to type 5 it will not allow the 5 leaving it as 1.

the logic for leap years and days in a month I understand but I can figure out how to prevent an input from a user.

I have tried a TextWatch but everytime I run it and type an invaild number it crashes my program
this is what I have it works but just tells the users the number is invalid

```
monthTXT.addTextChangedListener(textWatchers.birthDateWatcher(monthTXT, 1, 12))
```

```
fun birthDateWatcher(editText: EditText, minValue: Int, maxValue: Int): TextWatcher {
        return object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                val value = s.toString().toIntOrNull()
                if (value == null || value !in minValue..maxValue) {
                    editText.error = "Invalid value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Android ships with date widgets, why don't you use one of those? Not all the world uses the boneheaded month-day-year 'system' of writing, and it's way, way, _way_ more complex than you think it is. Folks paste dates. Why must one type '02' instead of '2'? That's needlessly user hostile. Silently ignoring input means if someone typoes and doesn't notice the input is a complete mess, whereas if you let it happen and just red-underline it, they can fix the typo.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I am aware of the date widgets built into Android I find them ugly and don't want to use it....2. whens the last time you pasted your birthdate into a from? 3. Regardless of what design I want. a simple typo and missing input for 8 characters I feel is such a nip-pick if you were born 2/4/99 and see MM/DD/YYYY most likely you will type 02 if not you will see you didn't type a 2 in the first place. 4. month-day-year system of writing is irrelevant to the question, I can just as easily make it day-month-year I just have no idea how to prevent an input depending on my min-max values

Comment: _whens the last time you pasted your birthdate into a from?_ Yesterday.